# Removing page footer and changing the page header in KOMA-SCRIPT chapters?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

My chapters are using `scrheadings`, as well my entire document. How can I remove the footer, only in chapter pages, and produce a different header?

Answer (score 4):

Adjust the page style `scrplain`, that's the style of chapter starting pages. You can do it by using the optional argument of the `scrpage2` commands such as `\ihead`, `\ohead` etc. It's described in the KOMA Script manual, just look for `scrplain`.

**Update**

With modern versions of KOMA-script package  `scrlayer-scrpage` deals with headers and footers`. The mechanism is the same though.

```
\ihead[chapterstart/plain]{\leftmark{} on normal pages}
\ofoot[soda pop]{\pagemark}
```

More information can be found in the KOMA-manual, as usual.

Comment: @JamieJ: Note also the command `\chapterpagestyle` with which you can set an other style than `scrplain` for chapter pages. See the [maual](http://www.bitlib.net/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf), e. g. page 66.